# PCI-bus load measurement in Linux

Tags: linux, pci-bus

I have a linux (3.12) system (x86-64) with multiple devices connected to the PCI bus (PCI-e). I would like to measure the PCI bus load in the current situation and again when I connect another device to the bus to see the difference, but I have no idea how. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to do this using Intel Performance Counter Monitor V2.7. I was lucky that since v2.5 an PCI-e bus monitor was added for x86 processors.